# How can I drop one element from a cell array?

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have some 1D cell arrays that look like this:

```
foo={'', 'some', 'important', '', 'data'}
```

I want to get rid of the empty strings that are scattered throughout the cell arrays, making something like this:

```
{'some', 'important', 'data'}
```

I know how to find the empty strings, but all of the documentation that I've been able to find regarding dropping elements from cell arrays leaves a something in the position being dropped. **How can I remove an element from a cell array, and have the resulting array shrink so as to only contain the relevant data?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Daniel mentioned, you can identify empty strings using `strcmp`. As an alternative to deleting the empty strings (i.e. `foo(is_empty_str)=[];`), you can select the non-empty ones:

```
is_empty_str = strcmp(foo,'');
foo = foo(~is_empty_str);
```

Both approaches produce the same result. Some people may prefer one over the other, mainly as a matter of coding style.

Answer (score 2):

You can identify empty strings using `strcmp(foo,'')`. To delete the first element from a cell array, use `foo(1)=[]`. In comparison `foo{1}=[]`assigns the empty list to the first element. Both combined is the solution:

```
>> foo(strcmp(foo,''))=[]

foo = 

    'some'    'important'    'data'
```